# JBO-27008: Attribute HQBranchIndicator in view object OrganizationParty cannot be set

Tags: c#, oracle, web-services, service-reference

I am getting an error when try to creation organization in the oracle webservice.
The field is set to nullable and I did not use that field. To resolve the issue I need to set HQBranchIndicator to empty string " ". But Other field error will occure there are too many fields to best. How to resolve this issue? Can i set all the fields to empty string?

```
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(IsNullable=true, Order=12)]
public string HQBranchIndicator {
            get {
                return this.hQBranchIndicatorField;
            }
            set {
                this.hQBranchIndicatorField = value;
                this.RaisePropertyChanged("HQBranchIndicator");
            }
}
```